# Unity 3d C# player movement difference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

What is difference between these two lines of codes?

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3 (rb.velocity.x, 5f,rb.velocity.z);

rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 5f,0);
```

both codes are in the this logic (if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))

Comment: `(if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))` ... please post [mcve] rather than a _snippet of a snippet_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you specify that velocity of your rigidbody should retain x and z value, and set y component of velocity to 5.

In the second example, you set velocity to the numbers you given.

If before setting value x and z values of rb.velocity were 0, both statements will do the same.

Comment: if both codes are in the this logic (if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))), what is the difference??

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? This seems reasonably easy. If you jump while standing still, effect will be the same. If you are moving and then you press jump, your character will stop and jump in place.

Comment: @yoyochan please post [mcve]